# gpg failed to sign the data. Failed to write commit object

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gnupg

I wrongly did `sudo install gpg` due to passphrase error. Now I am not able to commit anything through intelliJ. 
I am getting below error:

```
gpg: skipped "10XXXXXXXXX3892": secret key not available gpg: signing failed: secret key not available error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object 
gpg: skipped "MyUpdates": secret key not available gpg: signing failed: secret key not available error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Here two secret keys are shown "10XXXXXXXXX3892" and "MyUpdates". 
Is there any way i can get rid of gpg error. How can I uninstall gpg?

Answer (score 4):

This reads like a permissions problem. You likely created/installed the keys as another user than IntelliJ is running under. Given you run IntelliJ under your normal user account (which you generally should be doing), take ownership of the GnuPG home directory again:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg
```

Then make sure you can see the private keys:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```