# Unable to use Gcommit (Fugitive Plugin) on Vim when signing commits

Tags: git, macos, vim, gnupg, vim-fugitive

**CONTEXT**

Since I decided to sign all my commits, whenever I tried running `:Gcommit` and write a commit message I would get:

`fugitive: error: failed to sign the data`

I tried everything that people suggested on [this other question] ([gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object [Git 2.10.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0)) and also [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780874/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-failed-to-write-commit-object) but, apparently, it was just a different error.

Looking through the [issues on the Fugitive repository](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues), I noticed an **open** [issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/782) really close to what I was experiencing but without answer.

- **GPG** is installed through `brew`.
- **GPG Agent** is installed and running.
- Using **Vim** not *Neovim*
- All the symlinks are properly set.

**QUESTION**

How to sign commits inside Vim using Fugitive and GPG?

Answer (score 4):

After ignoring this feature for months, I finally found out a way to fix this!

The answer was on [this link](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36966517-issue-with-gpg-commit), kudos to "Blimmer":

`git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg)
echo "no-tty" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`

It worked for me!